# How can I display any image from photo library at full screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, photolibrary

In my iPhone program I need to choose any picture from the photo library and display it at full screen. 
I know how to work with picker and how to display at full size image that attached to project. But I still have no idea how to solve my task. Is there any way to do it?
I mean - display any image from photo library at UIImageView without giving the user the choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full screen means two things

1. Have a UIImageView which is 320x480 located at 0,0
2. Make sure the status bar is not displayed by using

```cpp
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Shai